# Conflict between different excel instances using VBA from Word

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, conflict

From a MS Word file, I have a VBA Macro that have to open an excel in invisible mode to get data from it. The problem is when I launch the macro it closes any other running excel instances and display an '1004' runtime error stating that << The rows method of the _global object failed >>.

```
Sub getDataFromExcel()
        Dim List
        Dim xlApp As Object
        Dim xlBook As Object
        Dim xlSheet As Object
        Dim xlSheetNum As Integer
        Dim iStarted As Boolean
        Dim lRow As Long
        Const strWorkBookName As String = "P:\Data_Source.xlsx"
        If Dir(strWorkBookName) = "" Then
          MsgBox "Cannot find the designated workbook: " & strWorkBookName, vbExclamation
          Exit Sub
        End If

        ' Test whether Excel is already running.
        On Error Resume Next
        iStarted = False ' Flag to record if we start Excel, so we can close it later.
        Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
        'Start Excel if it isn't running
        If xlApp Is Nothing Then
          Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
          If xlApp Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox "Can't start Excel.", vbExclamation
            Exit Sub
          End If
          ' Record that we've started Excel.
          iStarted = True
        End If
        On Error GoTo 0

        Set xlBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(FileName:=strWorkBookName, ReadOnly:=True)
        xlApp.Visible = False


        'Find the last non-blank cell in column A
         lRow = xlBook.Worksheets(1).Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row  '<<< this line causes the error

         List = xlApp.Transpose(xlBook.Worksheets(1).Range("A2:A" & lRow).Value)
         ' Do something with List

Set xlBook = Nothing
xlApp.Quit
Set xlApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

How can I avoid this type of conflict?

Comment: Can you provide the code you have? and also tell us which line causes the error

Comment: I have added the code  @Zac

Comment: I added Excel reference and qualified the `row` reference and all seems to work for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

qualify your `Rows` reference....

```
lRow = xlBook.Worksheets(1).Cells(xlBook.Worksheets(1).Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
```

Comment: Thank you @braX , It works, the error didn't show up again but running excel instances are still being closed.

Comment: I would recommend you remove your `On Error Resume Next` line of code and step thru it to find the exact line that is closing the running instances.

Comment: This line does xlApp.visible = False

Comment: I've added 3 lines to the code above that are actually at the end of the macro. When I comment the `xlApp.visible = false` then the `xlApp.Quit` closes all instances running too.

Comment: So you are saying that you only want to use Quit when a new instance was created? set a boolean value in the part where a new instance was created, and then check that variable before you issue the Quit.

Comment: To close just your workbook, use `xlBook.Close`. `xlApp` is the Excel application. If you close that, all open workbooks will be closed

Comment: Yeah you're right @Zac and thank you all for your time. What I finally came up with is to check if any other Workbook is active. If it is then I only close my data Workbook and If it's not I quit the excel application entirely. The same logic goes for the app visibility.

Comment: @Stackgeek Your current code is already set up to work out whether you created a new instance of Excel or not (`' Record that we've started Excel.` `iStarted = True`) - you just need to make use of that variable when closing the instance - i.e. `If iStarted Then xlApp.Quit`.  (And you should quit if you started the instance, otherwise that instance will continue to exist until you close Word.)  And the `xlApp.Visible = False` is not closing your existing instance of Excel (the `Quit` does that), it is just making it invisible - I don't think you have any need to use that line at all.

Comment: Thank you @YowE3K for your review. I really appreciate :). I have tried to use the `iStarted` variable as suggested buy @braX but got the same kind of behavior but maybe I didn't do it as I should. Anyway I will try it again on another Macro I'm writing today to see how it works. Thank you guys!